# Swiftの構造体への格納で、error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).というエラー

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

playgroundにて以下の様に構造体に格納しようとしたところ、

setVer([SIMD2(-1.0,-1.0),

の箇所にて

error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

というエラーが発生します。この様な場合どのように対処したらよいのでしょうか。

```
private var testver: [Test]!

struct Test {
    var testPos: SIMD2<Float>
    var testTex: SIMD2<Float>
    
    init(pos: SIMD2<Float>, ted: SIMD2<Float>) {
        self.testPos = pos
        self.testTex = ted
    }
}



func setVer(_ test: [SIMD2<Float>], coolt: [SIMD2<Float>]) {
    testver.append(Test(pos: test[0], ted: coolt[0]))
    return
}

setVer([SIMD2<Float>(-1.0,-1.0),
                      SIMD2<Float>(1.0,-1.0),
                      SIMD2<Float>(-1.0,1.0),
                      SIMD2<Float>(1.0,1.0)],
                     coolt: [SIMD2<Float>(1.0,1.0),
                                 SIMD2<Float>(0.0,1.0),
                                 SIMD2<Float>(0.0,0.0),
                                 SIMD2<Float>(1.0,0.0)])
```

Comment: `private var testver: [Test]!` - この変数宣言に、初期値代入が付属していません。`private var testver: [Test]! = []`と代入すると、表題のエラーメッセージを抑制できます。

Comment: 初歩的な漏れを失念してました。
```testver=[Test]()```
と入れていたのをなぜか削除していました。ありがとうございます。